# Is there a way to set serverside code to clientside scripts with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a couple of js files in my CakePHP project that need a path for ajax calls. I generate the paths on the server and want to pass them to the javascript in a generic way. I don't want to add them as a parameter to the function since they are static. Now I'm doing it like this:

```
<?php
    $categories = Router::url(array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'getChildCategories'));
    $brands = Router::url(array('controller' => 'brands', 'action' => 'autoComplete'));

    // first add the variables
    echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(
       'var CATEGORIE_GETSUBCATEGORY = "' . $categories . '";
       var BRAND_AUTOCOMPLETE = "' . $brands . '";',
       array('inline' => false)
    );

    // then include the file that uses them
    echo $this->Html->script('add'); 
?>
```

Is there a better way to do this without passing them as parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong at all with the way you're currently doing it. Any performance gains to be had are negligible and I don't think there is a definitively more elegant way of doing it.